# How to get top 60 percentage of rows in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements, ssms, percentage

Suppose my sql query returns some number of records. And I want only top 60% of them when the
the number of rows of that query gives more than 100k records.
If the number of rows doesn't exceed 100k, then I want all the records to be displayed.
How can I do that??

Comment: @shahkalpesh "If the number of rows doesn't exceed 100k, then I want all the records to be displayed.", with your suggestion, if 80k records are there you will miss the last 20k.

Comment: How to apply condition?

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use `case` statement inside the query.

So your query looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE your_condition ORDER BY some_column
  LIMIT 
      CASE 
          WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE your_condition) > 100000 THEN CEILING((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE your_condition) * 0.6)
          ELSE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE your_condition)
      END;
```

If you want to `run on SQL-Server` then your query will be:

```
SELECT TOP (
    CASE 
        WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE your_condition) > 100000 
            THEN CEILING((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE your_condition) * 0.6)
        ELSE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE your_condition)
    END)
    * FROM table WHERE your_condition ORDER BY some_column;
```

Comment: Itseems sql server doesn't support LIMIT and instead I have to use TOP. How can I put CASE condition within TOP. I tried it this way but didn't seem to work.                                   
            SELECT TOP 
   (CASE
    WHEN (COUNT(*) > 20000) THEN FLOOR(COUNT(*) * 0.6)
    ELSE (COUNT(*))
   END)
   * FROM.                                                                                                                        This is throwing the below error. Msg 162, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Invalid expression in a TOP or OFFSET clause.

Comment: @PikaPika I have added sql-server query in answer. You can check that query and give your feedback on it.

Comment: SELECT TOP (
    CASE 
        WHEN (COUNT(*) > 100000) THEN CEILING (COUNT(*) * 0.6)
  ELSE COUNT(*)
    END)
    *  FROM
(
SELECT.............                                                                                                                                I tried the same way but still getting the error saying Invalid expression in a TOP or OFFSET clause. Could you please check the above code and let me know where I am going wrong. Here I needed number of rows from the subquery. So, inside CASE I gave the condition only COUNT(*) instaed of selcting it from other table

Comment: @NIKUNJPATEL SQL Server does allow expressions for the args to TOP, but MySQL does not allow the args to LIMIT to be expressions.